# Unknown Bug Cause using MatLab's Genetic Algorithm

Tags: matlab

I'm new to MatLab and I'm writing a MatLab GA program to solve a particular scheduling problem.  The problem is I can't figure out the cause of one particular error.  This is main program:

```
1 FitnessFcn = @(seq)rate_fitness(seq,batch,obs);
2 MyPlotFcn = @(options,state,flag)rate_plot(options,state,flag,batch,seq,obs);
3 options = gaoptimset('PopulationType','custom','PopInitRange',[1;obs]);
4 options = gaoptimset(options,'CreationFcn',@rate_create,'CrossoverFcn', ...
    @rate_crossover,'MutationFcn',@rate_mutate,'PlotFcn',MyPlotFcn);
5 [seq,objfunc,reason,output] = ga(FitnessFcn,obs,[],[],[],[],[],[],[],options);
```

Here is the rate_plot function:

```
function state = rate_plot(options,state,flag,batch,seq,obs)
if strcmpi(flag,'init')
    cla;
end
{some code that works by itself}
end
```

Here is the rate_create function:

```
function pop = create_permutations(NVARS,FitnessFcn,options)
totalPopulationSize = sum(options.PopulationSize);
n = NVARS;
pop = cell(totalPopulationSize,1);
for i = 1:totalPopulationSize
    pop{i} = randperm(n);
end
```

The error I get (but ONLY when the 'PlotFcn' option is included) is:

```
Undefined function or variable 'seq'.

Error in @(options,state,flag)rate_plot(options,state,flag,batch,seq,obs)

Error in gadsplot>callOnePlotFcn (line 179)
optimvalues = plotfcn(varargin{1:end});

Error in gadsplot (line 132)
[state,optimvalues] = callOnePlotFcn(fname, plotNames{i}, state, options, ...
optimvalues, 'init', args{i}{:});

Error in gaunc (line 54)
state = gadsplot(options,state,currentState,'Genetic Algorithm');

Error in ga (line 348)
[x,fval,exitFlag,output,population,scores] = gaunc(FitnessFcn,nvars, ...

Error in rate_run (line 5)
[seq,objfunc,reason,output] = ga(FitnessFcn,obs,[],[],[],[],[],[],[],options);
```

Anyone have any ideas?  Tanks!